# Notation of derivative of theta 1 squared?

Tags: symbols, accents

I want to get the square of the derivative of theta 1. There are two options as far as I can see:

```
\dot{\theta}_1^2
```

or

```
\dot{\theta_1}^2
```

They produce different outputs. First one seems neater since 1 and 2 are of the same size and aligned but it is very condensed. Second one put 2 more top right but it seem a little unattached to the group. Here is a screenshot, first version is on the left, second version is on the right.

[image: theta]

What is the best way to get the result?

Comment: Is your question which one to choose? As you said you are looking for the derivative of theta1, i think the second one one be more logical. But we have some math-experts here with the real expertise ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Second one being more “logical”, but first one looking better (and, I think, the intended way of usage). I tend not to put braces whith single tokens accents, just `\dot\theta_1^2`.

Comment: My preference would be `(\dot\theta_1)^2`, explicitly delimiting the term in parentheses, though it really depends on context.  The second of examples you provided is, to my mind, not correct, because the dot is misplaced.

Comment: (In semi-response to Steven) Are there in your document the two different types? I mean, are there `\dot{\theta_1}` and `\dot{\theta}_1` while both have different meanings and can be confused? I guess not, and, in case that's the situation, I would choose the best looking one `\dot\theta_1^2`; in case you need to differentiate the two forms (which are present and easily confusable) I would have Steven's suggestion in mind `(\dot\theta_1)^2`.

Comment: @Manuel If one really preferred the exponent separated from the term, but did not want to use parens or to misplace the dot, one could also do (in math mode) `\makebox{$\dot\theta_1$}^2`

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about the general notational setup you use. E.g., is there also a `\theta_2`, `\theta_3`, etc in your document? Is the only power of `\dot{\theta}_1` going to be the second (square), or do third and higher powers occur as well?

Comment: I would really go for `\bigg(\frac{d\theta_1}{dt}\bigg)^2` both of them are really ugly and your readers would appreciate the explicit notation.

Comment: I use `\theta_1`, `\theta_1^2` normally. I am confused at derivative and its second power. There is also a term with 2 dots and power of 5.

Comment: `\dot{\theta}_1^2` is the right way, in my opinion.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Typing `\dot{\theta}_{1}^{2}` or `{\dot{\theta}_{1}}^{2}` is completely equivalent: if a subformula turns out to contain just an **Acc** atom, the braces are stripped off.

Comment: @egreg  Thanks.  I knew there was a way, but it did not come to me.

Comment: @percusse I think they are not “really ugly”; once one gets used to dot notation, it's nice one in my opinion.

Comment: @Manuel See the comment under egreg's answer why I think so.

Answer (score 5):

`$\dot\theta_1^2$`, and, in my opinion `${\dot\theta_1}^2$` too, produces an ambiguous form: it is not clear if you mean the derivative of `$\theta_1^2$` or the derivative `$\theta_1$`, squared.

Dots and primes are not a practical way of writing derivatives of larger expressions in general (and, as it appears, the square of something is large enough) because it is not clear what is being dotted or primed. (I keep seeing monstrous things like `$\left[loads\right]^\cdot$` in physics manuscripts.) If you want to use the dot notation, write `$(\dot\theta_1)^2$` because this makes explicit what you mean.

But maybe the best is, as @percusse said in the comments, to write `$\left(\frac{d\theta_1}{dt}\right)^2$` if the spatial arrangement is not a problem. (A minor point for this: in proper typesetting, the differential d is *not* italic, it should be `\mathrm{d}`. The Not So Short Introduction recommends to define this symbol as a custom command. It is unfortunate that there is nothing built in for this in LaTeX, nor is it known widely enough.)

Comment: `\dot{\theta_1}^2` is more correct in terms of form. However `\dot{\theta}_1^2` makes sense since subscript is obviously belonging to theta. I have to choose between these two since `\left(\frac{d\theta_1}{dt}\right)^2` would incredibly make formulas complex.

Comment: I see, `\frac{d\theta}{dt}` takes up a lot of space indeed. Then, if you want to be unambiguous, do use brackets. This is more of a matter of content than layout.

Comment: +1 for `(\dot\theta_1)^2` and making it explicit

Answer (score 2):

My preference would go to the simpler input

```
$\dot{\theta}_{1}^{2}$
```

If you feel that the exponent is too near to the variable, you can try

```
$\dot{\theta}_{1}^{\,2}$
```

[image]

However, I don't think the second way is preferable.

Comment: I have never thought using `\,` in superscript, thank you for the trick :)

Comment: It seems to me that the superscript needs to go vertically up not horizontally right.

Comment: @percusse I beg to disagree

Comment: It is of course a taste issue but how about `$\alpha\dot{\theta}_{1}^{\,2}\gamma$`?  :)

Comment: @percusse I see no problem. But a tastefully applied `\,` can help in some cases.

Comment: Sure no problem on that. I probably prefer seeing the square has a lower precedence than the dot operator so that it is not the derivative of squared theta. But in my last example the baseline of gamma and alpha looks really ugly and creates an illusion (maybe only to me)  as if theta and alpha is sshifted up.

Comment: @percusse Nice point about precedence. These terms comes from multiplication of same term with itself, so it is easily understandable that 2 belongs to derivative of theta 1 and not theta 1. However, syntactically, would expect 2 to appear more upright in this form.